# Can I answer my own question by citing a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, self-answer

The best answer on one of my questions is in the comment section.

I don't want to bother the commenter by asking for a formal answer so that I can give it the love (upvote and accept) that it deserves.

Is it acceptable to answer my own question with a summary of the comment, maybe providing additional insight? (I did this [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/511023/definition-of-gaussian-process/512563#512563), just now).

Comment: It would be nice if you made the answer community wiki, so you don't "benefit" from other peoples work.

Comment: Ah didn't know that was an option! Good idea, done.

Comment: @Luuklag so.... should I answer this question with a community wiki stating your comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely answer your own question if you get the answer from other user/s comment/s. It's also definitely a good idea to credit those user/s for their comment/s.

There are no rules for how you do this per se, but I suggest the following points to ensure that you give credit appropriately:

- Link directly to the user's account, since the username might be changed at some later point.
- Link to the comment/s directly, since that user may have posted multiple comments, and it might not be clear which comment/s you're referring to.
- Quote the comment directly, since comments are liable to be deleted at some later point for a variety of reasons.

So your answer would contain text that looks something like:

---

As pointed out by [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919) in their [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/511023/definition-of-gaussian-process/512563#comment943055_511023):

> See stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4364. Note that a joint Gaussian with nonzero covariances is always a linear transformation of a vector of independent Gaussian variables.

...

---

It's up to you whether you want to make the answer a Community Wiki (CW). In  my opinion, if the answer is composed *primarily* of the comments, then you should make it a CW. On the other hand, if you add your own explanation, or expand upon  the comments in any way, then you needn't make it a CW, since you should get credit (in the form of reputation) for your own contributions to the answer.